# What happens to GPT Partition after OS Reinstallation

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, gpt

I plan to reinstall a server 2008 OS, but i have other 4TB hard disks (G:,H:,I:)with GPT.

Would i loose the GPT config and all the data on other drives after reinstalling the OS on C:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you don't touch those other disks during the installation, and there's no RAID or mirroring going on, modifying the C: drive won't harm your other disks.

You should backup before reinstalling your OS, just because something can always go wrong. Or at the very least unplug those drives from your computer before installing the OS so that you can't accidentally wipe them.